# ST2 Having trouble firing triggers

Tags: syntax, sublimetext2

I am trying to create a syntax for Sublime Text 2 and any time I try to use the tab triggers I have set up, it will not trigger.

Source: https://github.com/Skullmonkey/IPS-BBCode

I am trying to take another languages files and create my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to fix your scope value. Try `"scope": "source.ipsbbcode - meta.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin"`. It's also probably useful to check the scope in your file to ensure it matches.